# How to efficiently perform syntactic analysis/parsing?

Tags: java, regex, parsing, token, text-parsing

My task is to implement a parser by hand, therefore using a parser generator is out of question. But I just can't find an efficient way to implement syntactic analysis. I have managed to do it "manually" but I'm afraid it's not only very inefficient but that I also have edge cases where it wouldn't work.

Suppose that I have a pseudo language, where variables are defined by the following syntax:

```
DECLARE-VAR. VARNAME.
```

Simultaneously, the language also establishes that for arithmetic operations, each arithmetic operator must be preceded and followed by white space. So
`X - Y` is correct but `X-Y` is incorrect.

And I want to build a parser (in Java for reference) that analyses the source code line by line and tell me if something is wrong with a line.

We already have a conflict there, since I'm declaring that `DECLARE-VAR` is valid syntax, while also saying that a `-` should be preceded and followed by white space.

So I manually check for this condition with:

```
if(!lineToCompare.toUpperCase().matches("[A-Z]+\\-[A-Z]+.*$") && lineToCompare.contains("-")){
                        char[] charArr = lineToCompare.toCharArray();
                        boolean problemWithOperator = false;
                        for(int i = 0; i < charArr.length;i++){
                            if(charArr[i] == '-' && (charArr[i-1] != ' ' || charArr[Math.min(charArr.length -1, i+1)] != ' ')){
                                System.out.println("A minus sign must be preceded and followed by white space")
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
```

And this work in most cases, but if I were to have the line

```
DECLARE-VAR. VARNAME. 1-2
```

My program won't consider it an issue because the line is matching `[A-Z]+\-[A-Z]+`, despite the fact that `1-2` should throw an error for having no spaces in between.

So I was wondering, is there an easier way to do this, which I'm missing? I was thinking about breaking up everything word by word, but I can't figure out a good way to check for the right characters if I can only check them 1 by 1, or if more than 1 issue occurs within the same line.

Comment: I need to do my own parsing to demonstrate it. This is just for a pseudo language so there's not many things to check for. My biggest problem right now is basically what I'm describing: The edge cases where you don't need to check a specific instance of a symbol because it's alright in its current position. I can add DECLARE-VAR to a HashMap of reserved words, but when I check for the validity of the minus signs in a line, it's going to run into the one from DECLARE-VAR and say its wrong

Comment: Sounds like you want to parse into tokens first (identifier, operator, whitespace etc)

Comment: @john3136 I really think that's the right way but that I'm missing something... For example, if I use tokens, my understanding is that I basically create a set of patterns to get the tokens, right? But how would I detect a case such as the one I described in my original post? If I created a pattern to get the minus signs, how would I check if those minus signs have spaces and they're not part of a reserved word?

Comment: I wouldn't use regex. Google Lexical Analysis. `DECLARE-VAR` seems to be a distinct token. The period is a token, whitespace is a token, `varname` is an identifier `1` is a literal `-` is an operator `2` is a literal so you end up with the series of tokens: DECLARE PERIOD WHITESPACE IDENTIFIER PERIOD WHITESPACE LITERAL OPERATOR LITERAL. which isn't legal - because the OPERATOR needs WHITESPACE on each side.